# form _submit not working in codignator

Tags: php

i don't know why form helper is not working, it doesn't submit data its just refreshing the same page and shows some field in url "http://localhost:8080/login/index.php/location/add?country_name=vfwq&city_name=csa&currency=f&symbol=w&mysubmit=Submit+Form"....

**View add.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
                            <fieldset>
                            <?php echo form_open('location/add_data'); ?>

                              <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="country_name">`enter code here`<?=$this->lang->line('location_countryname')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="country_name" type="text" name="country_name" value="<?=set_value('country_name')?>">
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="city_name"><?=$this->lang->line('location_cityname')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="city_name" type="text" name="city_name" value="<?=set_value('city_name')?>">
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="currency"><?=$this->lang->line('location_currency')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="currency" type="text" name="currency" value="<?=set_value('currency')?>">
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="symbol"><?=$this->lang->line('location_symbol')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="symbol" type="text" name="symbol" value="<?=set_value('symbol')?>">
                                </div>

                              <div class="form-actions">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary"  <?php echo form_submit('submit'); ?> <?=$this->lang->line('location_savechange')?></button>
                                <button class="btn"><?=$this->lang->line('location_cancel')?></button>
                              </div>

                              <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                            </fieldset>
                          </form>
```

**controller location.php**
class Location extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->load->model('location_m');
    $data['record']=$this->location_m->view();
    $data['mian_content'] = 'location/index';       
    $this->load->view('components/view_index', $data);

}




public function add()
{   
    $data['mian_content'] = 'location/add';     
    $this->load->view('components/view_index', $data);
}





public function add_data()
{   
    if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
    $data = array(
    'country_name'=>$this->input->post('country_name'),
    'city_name'=>$this->input->post('city_name'),
    'currency'=>$this->input->post('currency'),
    'symbol'=>$this->input->post('symbol'),
    );
    $this->load->model('location_m');
    $this->location_m->add($data);
    $data['mian_content'] = 'location/index';       
    $this->load->view('components/view_index', $data);
    redirect('location/index', 'refresh');
    }
```

**model location_m**

class Location_m extends CI_Model{

```
public function view()
{       
    $q = $this->db->get('country'); 
     if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
    }
    return $data;


}

public function add($data)
{       
    $q = $this->db->insert('country',$data);

    return;
}
```

Comment: you have form inside of form?

Comment: thanks men i rewired the hole code like for hundreds of times and it was just this silly mistake..

Comment: its working now Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `div` tags (the ones that have `control-group` as class).

Those errors are very easy to solve by properly indenting your code when you write it!

Answer (score 0):

You should take only one form. nested form is not working.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="location/add_data">
                              <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="country_name">`enter code here`<?=$this->lang->line('location_countryname')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="country_name" type="text" name="country_name" value="<?=set_value('country_name')?>">
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="city_name"><?=$this->lang->line('location_cityname')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="city_name" type="text" name="city_name" value="<?=set_value('city_name')?>">
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="currency"><?=$this->lang->line('location_currency')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="currency" type="text" name="currency" value="<?=set_value('currency')?>">
                                </div><br>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="symbol"><?=$this->lang->line('location_symbol')?></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="symbol" type="text" name="symbol" value="<?=set_value('symbol')?>">
                                </div>

                              <div class="form-actions">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary"  <?php echo form_submit('submit'); ?> <?=$this->lang->line('location_savechange')?></button>
                                <button class="btn"><?=$this->lang->line('location_cancel')?></button>
                              </div>


</form>
```